# MyISAM table is using filesort with ORDER BY, why?

Tags: mysql, myisam

Why is mysql using filesort when i order my selected rows with `ORDER BY x`?

My table looks likes this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
 `sdf` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `sdf33` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 KEY `sdf_2` (`sdf`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `sdf33` (`sdf33`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `sdf` (`sdf`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When running

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM  `test` 
ORDER BY sdf
```

mysql says it's using `filesort`, why? What do I need to change for it to not use `filesort`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FULLTEXT` index does not preseve ordering and can't be used for `ORDER BY`.

But even if you had a `BTREE` index on `sdf`, it most probably would not be used too, since it's generally more expensive to to the table lookups in a loop than scan the table sequentially and sort it.

The index would be of use for `ORDER BY / LIMIT`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test_sdf ON test (sdf);

SELECT  *
FROM    test
ORDER BY
        sdf
LIMIT   10
```

The `LIMIT` has a certain threshold after which the optimizer would prefer a filesort.

You can force the optimizer to use the index:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    test FORCE INDEX (ix_test_sdf)
ORDER BY
        sdf
```

if you really don't want to have a filesort.

Comment: I already have an ordinary `index`. It doesn't help. It's still using filesort.

Comment: @Marwelln: yes, and my answer explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Your fulltext index on `sdf` can't be used for an `ORDER BY` operation (they can only be used for `MATCH() ... AGAINST` queries) which is why it's using a filesort on the table.

The solution would be to add another regular index on `sdf` in addition to the fulltext index.

Answer (score -1):

add an index on sdf. and run the query again.